# Cron is sending empty array into my database

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron

I am running a file that reads a large json file and then saves the content to database.

When I am running the file directly, it saves the data

But when I am trying to run it via cron job, it is saving null into database.

Here is my code

```
include('conn.php');
$file = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices";
$json = file_get_contents($file);

updatePrice();

function updatePrice(){
global $con;
global $price;
$sql="INSERT INTO table(price) VALUES('$price')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo "price updated";

}}?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share your cron job?

Comment: What do you mean by 'running directly'?

Comment: How have you set up your cron job to run?

Comment: 'Running directly' means he is using his own id and executes the script. Is it correct Amir?

Comment: Please update your question to include both your cron-job and your actual code. If not, any answer will be pure speculation and guesses. Copy/paste the actual code. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tested if `file_get_contents()` is returning the content of the file via cronjob? You get a `null` by `json_decode()` if the string can't be decoded or the data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Comment: Guys the cron is set via cPanel and it is sending me emails.
Running the script directly means I am putting the url into my browser and it does the job .

Comment: @Tyr , file_get-contents() is returning the content and I checked it with an if statement but what you are saying about the recursion limit might be true.

But again when I am accessing the script directly by putting its path into the browser, it saves complete data into my database.

Comment: Since you don't seem to want to show us your actual code and I'm not in the mood for a guessing game, I'm out...

Comment: Updated the code. Sorry I didn't read that comment before.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the value of location of the file is absolute rather than relative path. Cron job is using another id (usually root) so you need to explicitly use /home/userid/path/to/file.txt rather than ./file.txt.
Hope this helps. Thanks.

Edited: This also applies to your function file_get_contents.

Comment: That is an external file and the first thing i did was to check if the file is being included or not.

There is no problem with the file.

Is there anything related to data size? Is there any limitation on the size of the data we can send via cron?

Comment: I don't mean the file itself. If you put ./file.txt as location of the file, then cron job will not find this file but if you put /home/userid/pat/to/file.txt then cron will see the exact location of the file in the server.

Comment: Sir, the I have setup the cron via cpanel and it is sending me the log of every execution.

Comment: I wouldn't presuppose the cron-job is running under root.

Comment: The problem has been solved. I used cURL instead of file_get_contents()

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable error reporting on your script and take a look for warnings or errors.
2. Check if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled for cli (some systems have separate .ini files for cli and web). You can do `php --info` to check which file is used on the cli.
3. I strongly recommend not using `file_get_contents()`, because it doesn't handles redirects or delays in response. Try cURL instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried cURL and it solved the problem.